# Android: Added project as library, getting (missing) .jar file in Build Path>Libraries>Library Projects

Tags: android, eclipse, properties, jar

Ok, I've been trying to find a solution for this for about half a day now.

I have two projects in the workspace. One is the main, I'll call it Alpha, the other is used as a library to the main, I'll call it Delta.

Delta has "is Library" check marked, and has no errors (only yellow triangles with an exclamation mark).

Alpha has Delta added as a library (under the Android selection in Project Properties). Once that is done, I get a big, fat, red exclamation mark by Alpha. In Alpha's Build Path, under the Libraries tab, there's a red 'x' by "Library Projects." Upon expanding that option I see:

```
delta.jar - /Users/.../Delta/bin (missing)
```

I really can't understand why that would be missing. 1st, the bin folder is there. 2nd, I'm importing a project library, not a .jar. 3rd even if it's creating a .jar file of the project library, it seems to compile right, Delta has no erros.

I'm really in the dark here. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: I've had issues in Eclipse/Android with importing libraries.  Are you able to just export it as a .jar?  That solved my problems when I attempted to do a similar thing (I was writing an advertising SDK as a .jar)

Comment: Stupid question here... but did you try cleaning and rebuilding (both the library project and your own project)?

Comment: Yes...several times in fact. Pretty much everytime I change something (related to his issue) I'm cleaning, and rebuilding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SDK Tools, revision 14, and ADT 14.0.0 and upwards, there are changes to how  jar-based libraries are built. I encourage you to read library project revamp [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14)

Comment: I updated to 14 since AdMob will tell you to update to the latest ADT version, and that's when hell broke loose. Thanks for you link, things make more sense now. I had now idea they have changed that. I still have issues, but now I know WHY.

Comment: Good. i had the same experience and it took me some time to figure out what was happening. :-)

Comment: @EdGs can you please explain what was the problem as i am still stuck in same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem specifically when I upgraded to Android SDK 18 on OSX.  Neither marking a project as a library, or importing an existing library project would generate the jar file.

I upgraded to 19 and it went away, now the jars are generated and I've done absolutely nothing else to the project or settings at all.

Hope this helps someone, I struggled for hours just like the OP.