# Android Library Does not generate a jar file in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

First time I have had this problem.  I have an Android Library project in eclipse. Its marked as a library.  But it does not generate any jar file.  I have run the exact same code on another windows machine and the jar file is generated?  What could be the problem? I have cleaned the project. I look and see there are class files, but the jar file is not generated, and the biggest surprise is that there are absolutely no errors shown in eclipse.

The library I developed in eclipse on window 64 bit, setup eclipse and android jdk 1.6 on 32 bit imported the project and it won't generate the library. I see jarlist.cache in bin but no jar file. On 64 bit machine it runs fine. Whats going on here?  Eclipse seem oblivious to the fact that the library was not generated. No messages at all ...

Answer (score 1):

It's how it works. The name may be misleading, but Android Library project is not meant to produce jar files. It is to be included in other projects and built together with them.

Comment: but there are ways to make a Android Library produce a jar file. Are you saying that if I add the project to one that seeks to include it only then will it produce the jar file?

Comment: Part of the reason for not simply producing a jar is that library projects can contain resources. If you don't have resources in your library project, try building it in Eclipse and check if it generates a /bin directory with a jar inside of that.

Comment: resources -> generate jar or don't generate jar. Not sure what you are saying here.  Why is there not a simple generate jar directive for a library. I mean that's what libraries usually are.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are created by later versions of the Android SDK.  See this question for more details, and my answer on how I fixed this:

[Android: Added project as library, getting (missing) .jar file in Build Path>Libraries>Library Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897916/android-added-project-as-library-getting-missing-jar-file-in-build-pathlib)